# OAuth 1.0a Implementation with PHP Pecl - Custom Signature (Fitbit)

Tags: php, oauth, fitbit

I had an implementation of OAuth working with Fitbit to pull data from fitbit's service.  However they recently updated their service and now the request is failing whenever I try to get an access token.

They have made the following statement about the new requirement:

```
The solution is to OAuth sign the requests to <https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token> and <https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token> in a similar manner that all other calls to the Fitbit API are signed. 

Requests to <https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token> need to be signed with your application's consumer key and secret. 
Requests to <https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token> need to be signed with your application's consumer key and secret and the oauth_token and oauth_verifier received from the authorization callback.
```

I am using the PHP PECL OAuth library for OAuth requests.  However I can't find a way to add additional parameters to the signature.  I am trying the following but I'm not sure that this is the correct way to update the OAuth Signature:

```
$params['consumer_key'] = $this->consumer_key;
$params['consumer_secret'] = $this->consumer_secret;
$params['oauth_token'] = $this->oauth_token;
$params['oauth_verifier'] = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

$this->signature = $this->oauth->generateSignature('GET', $this->access_url, $params);
$this->access_token = $this->oauth->getAccessToken($this->access_url, $this->signature, $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
```

The OAuth error I get is:

```
401
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
oauthoauth_signatureInvalid signature: FfvYDv5MSOfwcOwLZBJa0TlKS4Q=false
```

The signature which is stored from the code above shows that the proper signature should be:

```
[signature] => wlfzqPs4aEkTkHfqyaO65D/RW6o=
```

This is the "Headers Sent" piece of the debug information:

```
[headers_sent] => Authorization: OAuth oauth_session_handle="Frdnxw8oHe3BgNVi0Fy4jBXrZko%3D",
oauth_verifier="ss6nmke8elf3so66jg3auued49",
oauth_consumer_key="(my key)",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_nonce="30463910852ea5cc2d04e60.71895372",
oauth_timestamp="1391090882",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_token="2cabd6beab341e332bdf8e522b6019ef",
oauth_signature="hULwWcQOl%2F8aYjh0YjR843iVXtA%3D"
```

I can't find anything in the documentation which explains how I can set the signature for OAuth to use with it's request.  Any Help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Please let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

It turns out I was not saving the `oauth_token_secret` being handed back and I was instead using the consumer secret.

Once I updated this, the process ran as expected.